# Elasticsearch: Manipulate score by field value number

Tags: elasticsearch

I use Elastic for searching pdf's.
One of the fields apart of the pdf-content is doridat, what is a date as integer. The newest documents should get a higher score (higher ranking). This means that the higher the value in the doridat field, the higher the score should be. Only the result from searching in attachment.content and doridat should influence the score.

**How can I force the scoring to integrate the field (doridat) value?**

My query:

```html
GET /attachments/_search 
{  
  "size": 2,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "attachment.content": {
        "value": "*berg*",
        "rewrite": "scoring_boolean"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight":{
    "fields":{
      "attachment.content":{}
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "excludes": "attachment.content"
  }
}
```

My mapping:

```html
{
  "attachments" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "attachment" : {
          "properties" : {
            "author" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "content" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "content_length" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "content_type" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "creator_tool" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "date" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "description" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "detect_language" : {
              "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "format" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "indexed_chars" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "keywords" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "language" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "metadata_date" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "modified" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "title" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "content" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "daname" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "do__nr" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "do_typ" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "doext" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "doname" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "donr" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "doridat" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "dowww" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "path" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think wildcard always returns `1.0` for a match (even if matched more than once).

[Rank feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rank-feature.html) looks interesting for your use case. You'll need to duplicate the `doridat` field and index it with the `rank_feature` field type. You'll be able to use that field in a [Rank feature query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-rank-feature-query.html). What Elasticsearch version do you use?

Another option is to use a [Script score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html). You can basically return `doridat` in the script since wildcard always returns `1.0` as score. You can use an [N-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) for `attachment.content` to achieve a wildcard like query. When you use `match` instead of a `wildcard`, it will score matches better.

The docs state that rank feature has better performance (it can skip documents when searching).

Comment: I'm using version 8.2. Using the line "rewrite": "scoring_boolean" a real score is set (instead of "1").